# Remove ROS from Yocto Bitbake to Reduce Image Size

Tags: yocto, ros, bitbake, arago

I pulled a default Arago/yocto image to build using bitbake and the output image is 8 GB. I need to reduce the size ot be less than 4 GB, so I tried to remove the meta-ros layer. I am getting an error, but cannot determine the source of the error:
`ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'packagegroup-ros-ti' (but /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_ti/sources/meta-arago/meta-arago-distro/recipes-core/images/tisdk-rootfs-image.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)`
(*yes, that is the whole error message and seems very grammatically incorrect and I got confused when I re-read it...*)

Then `tisdk-rootfs-image.bb` says nothing about ROS and I can't find (grep -r ros) where ros is required.

How can I figure this out or what depends on ROS.

Bonus points for figuring out other things I can remove (I need GStreamer, but *I don't think* that I need qt5. Also I don't need any examples, samples, demos, etc).

Comment: I guess its a constant size raw image. is it using wic to generate image ? if so you might be able to adjust the kickstart file

Comment: I have no clue if it is using wic. How can I tell? Is there something that I can look for?

Comment: which target did you use?

Answer (score 0):

How about building your own image up, instead of starting from a large image and trying to cut bits out?  Much easier to build up than down.