# Is ROS installed by default in Arago?

Tags: yocto, ros, arago

I am trying to learn about Arago, still a beginner. Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61376427/remove-ros-from-yocto-bitbake-to-reduce-image-size)  gives me the impression that ROS is by default installed in the default Arago image.

Is this understanding correct? Is ROS (or the meta-ros layer) installed by default in Arago?
Any tips where to get more information is very welcomed